# ListView and Array Adapters in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

How do you pass an Arraylist of objects into an adapter, and then into a listview?  I'm trying to pass the Group Name, which is a property of Group, into the listview.   If it is possible, I would also like to pass the ID as a value (in case of a click).

```
private void populateList(){

        // Enable Local Datastore.

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Group.class);

       //PARSE INITI REMOVED 

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group");
       // query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("Name", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " groups");

                    for (ParseObject gGroup : scoreList) {
                        Log.d("Name", "Retrieved " + gGroup.toString() + " groups");
                        Group newGroup = new Group();
                        newGroup.setName(gGroup.toString());

                       listGroups.add(newGroup);


                    }




                } else {
                    Log.d("Name", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        //build

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.da_list,R.id.name,listGroups);

        //list
        ListView mGroups = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.uiGroups);

        mGroups.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

XML View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListMenuItemView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The title and summary have some gap between them, and this 'group' should be centered vertically. -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:duplicateParentState="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ListMenuItemView>
```

Comment: you need to either write your own adapter by extending BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter<T> or use pre defined adapters if the designs are simple. Follow this tutorial for better guidance:
http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9

Comment: Write your own custom adapter extending BaseAdapter and pass your List into that adapter. See this- http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Comment: Yes, you have to write you own Adapter that extends BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own Adapter. The skeleton looks like this :

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Group> {

  private Context mContext;
  private ArrayList<Group> mGroup;

   public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> group) {

      mContext = context;
      mGroup = group;
   }

   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

       TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);
       textView.setText(mGroup.get(position).getGroupName());
       return rowView;
    }
}
```

*Note* : This adapter does not take into account possible improvements to the management of the ListView. look at this link for more precision : http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Where `R.layout.rowlayout` is something like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now you have to set this adapter to your ListView :

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), groupArrayList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Have a nice day !